# What is the best way to add co-inventor item in your CV

Tags: patentability, ownership, granted, curriculum, cv

I am a co-inventor in a filed patent. I want to properly mark this in my CV. As far as I can understand the concept correctly, first of all, since I am one of number of inventors I am a "co-inventor". Does that also makes me a "patent owner"? Also should I write the date it is filed AND the date it is granted/issued (is granted or issued the correct term)? I need to add the number of the patent when it is issued/granted right? Also the country, which in my case is France? Searched the Internet for a correct template but there got confused. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is understand what the terms mean. It is okay to call yourself a "co-inventor" on a patent application, just be sure you call a patent application an "application". You also need to understand that a patent application does not mean a patent will ever issue. It can take a few successful patents before you understand if you're likely to be successful or not, but the good news is that so few people ever have applications submitted that just getting that far looks good on your CV.

You don't have to list the owner on your CV. A patent demonstrates technical prowess and is your intellectual accomplishment. It may be obvious from the filing date who is the owner ("assignee"), but again -- this is your intellectual accomplishment, you do not have to list the employer.

The format I use is to have a section which typically has a heading like "Relevant Patents" or "Relevant Patents and Applications". I have a lot. I pick and choose which ones I put on my CV. I didn't look up the portfolio of the other respondent, but I've also use that format when I had fewer -- "Patents Granted". The other respondent may just be listing a few of theirs as well.

If this sounds like "it depends on how many patents you have and what else you can put on your CV", that would be correct. When I only had 2 or 3 patents, I merged my patents with publications. Then I had more patents and publications and made separate sections. Then I had a ton of patents, some publications and conference presentations I hated, and I became selective. You will want to look at how much different kinds of material you have. Three sections for "Patents", "Publications" and "Conference Presentations", where each section has one entry looks really sad on a CV.

When I interview someone who lists "Patents", I make sure the patents were actually issued, and I read the patent or application. Make sure you provide enough information -- title of the patent application, application or patent number, country where filed or issued. Your interviewer will likely want to see what it is you and your co-inventors came up with.

Best of luck with the patent application!

Answer (score 0):

I have listed patents that I'm an inventor of on my CV. Unlike academic publications, I don't think there is specific format you need to follow. You don't need to state you are a co-inventor, just state you are listed as an inventor. List the patent number. If the patent hasn't issued, but an application has published, you can list the publication number. This makes it possible for the person reading the patent to look up the patent or application. If they bother to do this, they will see the other inventors and the application date. I list just the patent number and title on my CV. There is nothing keeping your from listing the co-inventors too, but since space on a CV is often tight, it isn't necessary. I suppose if the application hasn't published you might list a date, but I haven't. It is very common for the same invention to be filed for a patent in multiple countries. You could list each separately, but I only list one in the patent family (generally the US patent). For me this is in the interest of saving space. An example of what my CV looks like is the following.

> U.S. Patents Granted (World and European equivalents not listed.)
>
> 9,222,886: Quantitating high titer samples by digital PCR  
> 8,409,528: Apparatus and Method for Handling Fluids for Analysis  
> ...etc...

Being an inventor and a patent owner are two different things. I have many patents I'm listed as an inventor on, but I'm the owner of none of them. In every case, the company that employed me is the owner (assignee) of the patent. This is the normal situation for patents that come about as a result of working for a commercial company.

Comment: So yes it is only filled at this point and it is not issued/granted. I am also in a commercial company, so it is the owner of the patent right? Not me? I am only a co-inventor. Where can I retrieve this publication number from? Maybe a french site for patents? I don't really know

Comment: @nmrlqa4 Applications typically publish 18 months after filing. Your company’s patent lawyers might be able to provide an application number. Don’t say you are only a “co-inventor”, you are an inventor! Many if not most patents have multiple inventors.

Comment: I am not sure about the co-inventor thing? Should I really? We are group of 10 people. How should I know if I am an inventor or a co-inventor?

Comment: To be listed as an inventor on a patent, you should be responsible for at least one novel thing captured by the claims. Thus you are an inventor. Since the application hasn't published, you could list the application title and the full list of inventors if you want, but that takes a lot of space if there are ten inventors. If you want to use the term "co-inventor" you certainly can. What I was trying to convey is that you aren't "only" a co-inventor.  Ii your patent is granted, in my eyes that is just as impressive whether or not there are multiple inventors on the patent.